# sql mass insert. Need help

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hi I doing a mass insert of records from this text file using the script below. I having a problem here to set the "c:\" to a parameter I pass in from a vb .net application? I do not want to define a fixed path for that. IS that possible?

```
INSERT INTO tblContacts
SELECT     *
FROM         [Text;Database=C:\;HDR=Yes].[Import.csv]
```

Comment: What DB are you using?  SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? Postgres? Also, is the program running on the local server?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I using ms access. any solutions? 

Let me explain a bit on my scenario. My app was running fine with my Win xp Pc with the predefined c:\ path. But when i try to write the csv file to a vista or windows 7 pc there is a access denied on the c:\. I guess it a security measurement. Is there a way to bypass it ? I thinking of an alt solution.

Comment: Just save the file somewhere else (`%APPDATA%` comes to mind).

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use any scripting language (or maybe VBA) to parse the SQL file, change the path, write it again, then batch-run the changed SQL file.

Answer (score 0):

Write the path as `%TEMP%\Import.csv`.  This is a special shortcut to get to the temp folder.  You will have access to write to the user's temp folder.

Comment: I try these 2 method but still cannot

Comment: [Text;Database=%APPDATA%\;HDR=Yes].[Import.csv]
[Text;Database=%TEMP%\;HDR=Yes].Import.csv] Did I write the wrong code?

Comment: you're sure the file exists in %appdata%/%temp%?